# Polar Plot Radial range

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to change radial range in `PolarPlot` so that oscillations could be more visible:

```
PolarPlot[{1, 1 + 1/100 Sin[10 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

In order to do so, the range should not start from zero, but from a certain value. Can anyone help with this one?

Comment: Given that cutting a disk out of the center changes nothing, the only way forward is to scale the radial distance in a polar plot by some compressive nonlinearity, for instance $r \to \sqrt{r}$.

Comment: I found a naive way using `Rescale` : 
`MinR = 0.97;
MaxR = 1.03;
SclFunc[x_] := Rescale[x, {MinR, MaxR}];
PolarPlot[
 {SclFunc@1, SclFunc@(1 + 1/100 Sin[10 t])}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
 , PlotRange -> 1.2
 , PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 1}
 , PolarAxes -> True
 , PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", {{0, MinR}, {0.5, (MinR + MaxR)/2}, {1, 
     MaxR}}}
 ]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

If you plot the [`Log`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html), then the baseline (r == 1) is zero, above the baseline is a positive radius, and below the baseline is a negative radius.

```
pplt = Legended[
 PolarPlot[Log[1 + 1/100 Sin[10 t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t, r}, ColorData["Rainbow"][r]]],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {Log[0.99], Log[1.01]}}]];

Animate[
 Show[pplt,
  Graphics[{Black, AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Point[Log[1 + 1/100 Sin[10 t]] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}]],
 {{t, 0, Style["θ", 14]}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 AnimationRate -> .0075]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a way of carving a circular hole out of the plot as you suggest, but perhaps you could concnetrate on one side of the function:

```
With[{center = 0.67, range = 0.2},
 PolarPlot[
  {1, 1 + 1/100 Sin[10 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  AxesOrigin -> {center, center},
  PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{center - range, center + range}, 2]
 ]
]
```

[image: portion of plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I'm trying to plot some experimental data and a fitting to them to show symmetry of a system , so the whole 2 pi range would be very useful. Maybe there is way to combine few  such sides in one plot? Or there is another way , not necessarily with PolarPlot but still carving the hole?

Comment: @Adam I am not sure that I can imagine how to meet your two requirements at the same time. They seem physically incompatible.